# How can I make this into a frequency or a pattern that will get repeated like a triangle wave?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, functions

This is called a triangle wave, and I don't know what function generates these waves:

[image]

Using these functions, I created this:

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/p6tsryxso0

[image]

How can I make this into a frequency or a pattern that will get repeated like a triangle wave?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're looking for. Do you want to extend the pattern you've created periodically?

Comment: "don't know what function generates these waves"?  On $(-1/2, 1]$, the line $2x+1$ and on $(1,1/2]$, the line $1-2x$.  Repeat this with period 1.  Or maybe you are asking for the Fourier series to "generate" this?

Comment: You can plot that function in Desmos by repeatedly entering `y=|2x-(2k+1)| {k<x<k+1}` for integer $k$. I'm not sure there is a built-in way to plot a non-trigonometric periodic function - assuming that's what you actually want.